# Docker containers are running but can't find them

Tags: docker

Yesterday I created 1 network and 3 containers for prestashop, phpmyadmin and mysql.
I saved them by running a `docker save` command and today when I came back my containers are still working on the specified ports however I can't see the containers by running `docker ps -a`. Also the prestashop folder is not writable anymore.

How can I see where my docker containers that are running ?

`docker ps -a` :

```
CONTAINER ID   IMAGE     COMMAND   CREATED   STATUS    PORTS     NAMES
```

`docker network ls` :

```
NETWORK ID     NAME                         DRIVER    SCOPE

e03870bf5fec   bridge                       bridge    local
63cfaacfbb2e   chrono                       bridge    local
c23a0b85edb9   host                         host      local
1ae1b68b12c0   none                         null      local
```

`docker images` :

```
REPOSITORY          TAG          IMAGE ID       CREATED       SIZE

<none>              <none>       5fab8d650e42   4 hours ago   657MB
prestadock_apache   latest       740c640530f3   2 days ago    657MB
phpmyadmin          latest       f7fd780fedba   7 days ago    469MB
php                 7.4-apache   899ab23566b7   7 days ago    414MB
mysql               latest       c8562eaf9d81   10 days ago   546MB
```

`docker-compose.yml` :

```
version: "3.8"
services:

  db:
    image: mysql:latest
    command: --default-authentication-plugin=mysql_native_password
    container_name: chrono_db
    restart: always
    volumes:
      - db-data:/var/lib/mysql
    environment:
      - MYSQL_ROOT_PASSWORD=root
    networks:
      - dev

  phpmyadmin:
    image: phpmyadmin:latest
    container_name: chrono_phpmyadmin
    restart: always
    depends_on:
      - db
    ports:
      - 8081:80
    environment:
      PMA_HOST: db
    networks:
      - dev

  apache:
    build: php
    container_name: chrono_prestashop
    ports:
      - 8080:80
    volumes:
      - ./php/vhosts:/etc/apache2/sites-enabled
      - ./:/var/www/html
    restart: always
    networks:
      - dev

networks:
  dev:

volumes:
  db-data:
```

`Dockerfile` :

```
FROM php:7.4-apache

RUN echo "ServerName localhost" >> /etc/apache2/apache2.conf

RUN apt-get update \
    && apt-get install -y --no-install-recommends locales apt-utils git libicu-dev g++ libpng-dev libxml2-dev libzip-dev libonig-dev libxslt-dev;

RUN echo "en_US.UTF8 UTF8" > /etc/locale.gen && \
    echo "fr_FR.UTF-8 UTF-8" >> /etc/locale.gen && \
    locale-gen

RUN curl -sSk https://getcomposer.org/installer | php -- --disable-tls && \
    mv composer.phar /usr/local/bin/composer

RUN docker-php-ext-configure intl
RUN docker-php-ext-install pdo pdo_mysql gd opcache intl zip calendar dom mbstring zip gd xsl
RUN pecl install apcu && docker-php-ext-enable apcu
RUN a2enmod rewrite && service apache2 restart
RUN chown -R www-data:w
```

Here is the error after running `docker-compose up -d` :

```
ERROR: for chrono_prestashop  Cannot start service apache: driver failed programming external connectivity on endpoint chronopiles_prestashop (11458be3c31e5f1107770b98ec5e56c645ac9e68b742fd4eb41ad965bd641e9c): Error starting userland proxy: listen tcp 0.0.0.0:8080: bind: address already in use
```

Comment: Can you provide a [mcve] showing your images' Dockerfiles, how you started the containers originally, and why you think the directory is absent?  If you're missing images, can you `docker build` them again from their Dockerfiles?

Comment: sorry if it was missing informations, I edited with the the docker-compose and Dockerfile. I could probably rebuild them but I want to understand why they disappeared from my containers and still working in case it happens again. I don't want to re-build them everyday, I only have 3 containers atm but if I work with more this will get annoying.

Comment: The `restart: always` should cause the containers to get recreated at boot time, but if not, it should just be running `docker-compose up -d` to recreate them.

Comment: Yes, I want them to always restart and work. And currently they are working the only thing is that I can't manage to find the containers, so whenever I try to run `docker-compose up -d` that the bind is already in use